Adding Environment Variable to Local Wordpress Instance created with @wordpress/env
I am using the @wordpress/env package to start a local wordpress instance to test my tool development.
The plugin I am developing is required to use some environment values that I know to be present in the production environment. To test it locally I wanted to add a variable to the environment but I could not find a solution to add them in the documentation here.

you can use classic WordPress environment variables.
set it in your wp-config.php file :
define('NAME', VALUE);

Then you can call it this way :
$VARIABLE = getenv('NAME');


Thanks for your reply, the package offers the .wp-env.json with config field. These values are not getting mapped as env variable.  I do not know where the wp-config.php file is located with the approach listed in the documentation.

it's a the root of the wordpress code, your package has his own namespace that does not gives you reel environment variable, just globals for this pakage. If you want reel environment variable use the example bellow.
